# How to count how many words Are in text Area in Java GUI Program

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I am trying to make a program that counts how many words there are in a text file. My aim is that once the text is visible in the textArea that it can count all the words in it.

My code for opening the .txt files is this :

```
Action Open = new AbstractAction("Open File") {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            if (fc.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                openFile(fc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
            }
        }
    };

    public void openFile(String fileName) {
        FileReader fr = null;
        try {
            fr = new FileReader(fileName);
            textArea.read(fr, null);
            fr.close();
            setTitle(fileName);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I have seen people outputting the individual words in the console for example the =11 but what I want is to replace the text in the textArea with "fileName has x number of words"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!
Please
take the [tour](/tour), have a look around, and
read through the [help center](/help), in particular
[How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic). From that second link: "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."

Comment: Use a `DocumentFilter`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Updated

Suddenly realised that I might have taken the question to literally

Perhaps you meant something more like...

```
String text = // Text from the file...

int letterCount = text.length();
int wordCount = text.split("\\s").length;
String result = "[insert file name here] has " + letterCount + " characters and " + wordCount + " words";

// A JTextArea you created eailer
textArea.setText(result);
```

## Original answer

> but what I want is to replace the text in the textArea with "fileName has x number of words"

I'm not really sure that's exactly what you mean, but...

The best place to start (for this requirement) would be a `DocumentFilter`

It will allow you to filter the text been applied to the `Document`/`JTextArea` and replace it with what ever text you want.

Maybe something like this...

```
public class WordCounterDocumentFilter extends DocumentFilter {

    @Override
    public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length, String text, AttributeSet attrs) throws BadLocationException {
        int letterCount = text.length();
        int wordCount = text.split("\\s").length;
        String result = "[insert file name here] has " + letterCount + " characters and " + wordCount + " words";
        super.replace(fb, 0, fb.getDocument().getLength(), result, attrs);
    }

}
```

Which could then use something like this...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument;
import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.DocumentFilter;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            JTextArea ta = new JTextArea(10, 20);
            add(new JScrollPane(ta));
            ta.setEditable(false);

            ((AbstractDocument)ta.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(new WordCounterDocumentFilter());
            ta.setText("This is a bunch of text");
        }

    }

    public class WordCounterDocumentFilter extends DocumentFilter {

        @Override
        public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length, String text, AttributeSet attrs) throws BadLocationException {
            int letterCount = text.length();
            int wordCount = text.split("\\s").length;
            String result = "[insert file name here] has " + letterCount + " characters and " + wordCount + " words";
            super.replace(fb, 0, fb.getDocument().getLength(), result, attrs);
        }

    }

}
```

Which would output something like this...

[image: Example output]

Comment: //Decided to do it like this however
//when there are no lines it reads it as one line 
 `private void countWords() {`
  `String text=textArea.getText ();`
  `int countWord=text.split("\\s").length;`
  `textArea.setText("Number of Words : "+countWord);`

Comment: One last question when I try to count and empty field it still counts it how can I fix that. What i mean is try and count it without there being any text and it outputs 1.

Comment: First, trim the `String` of leading/trailing white spaces (`String#trim`), then check the length of the resulting `String`, if it's `0`, then it has no words

Comment: If you use \s+ instead of \s as your regular expression it won't count new lines, giving you a more accurate result.

Comment: @Tymek Needs drives must, but since the question itself was some what vague, so is the answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

First get value from textarea

`String text=textArea.getText ();`

Now use length function to get string length.

`int countWord=text.length();`

Now print in console

`System.out.println ("No of Words : "+countWord);`

Comment: That would be the number of characters